# Vertical adjustment of side caption

Tags: vertical-alignment, sidecap

I have a long table, which I want to start in the margin of my document. However, I am using  side captions, and to avoid the table to overlap the caption, I would like to move the caption down a bit. How can I do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{sidecap} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{sidecaption}{Text text text}[tab:test]
        \centering
        \sffamily\footnotesize
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-25mm}{0mm}  
                \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
                    \toprule
                    \textbf{AAAAAAAAAA} & \textbf{BBBBBBBBBB} & \textbf{CCCCCCCCCCC} \\
                    \midrule
                    1 & 2 & 3 \\
                    4 & 5 & 6 \\
                    \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
        \end{adjustwidth}
        \end{sidecaption}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it not more sensible to put caption below/above of your table, i.e. not use of sidecaption?

Comment: It depends. But it is at not a solution for me.

Comment: You load `sidecap.sty` but only use the `sidecaption` environment supplied by `memoir`. The `SCtable` environment supplied by `sidecap` seems to do a better job, putting the normal `\caption` on the right in this case (where it ought to be). It seems not to play well with `adjustwidth`, but one can instead use a simple `\hspace` to move the tabular left. Also, `\centering` seems contraindicated if you want the `tabular` to extend into a margin.